# How to extract img tag src from ascx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want `img` `src` values on page load (ascx) page. How can I do this in ASP.NET C#. Consider there are 5 images on the page (ascx). I want to save the URLs of all 5 images into a database by receiving it on btnclick event. How can I do this?

Code:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb(); 
var doc = web.Load("stackoverflow.com";); 
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"); 

foreach (var node in nodes) { 
    Console.WriteLine(node.src); 
}
```

The above code is to get img src. But how to use htmlweb() in c# .net?

Comment: do you use `asp:Image` to display them?

Comment: var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(node.src);
        }

Comment: above code is to get img src . But how to use htmlweb() in c# .net

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
void Btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Get your path
  string  path = yourImageButtonId.ImageUrl;
  //Save on your database
  //Here you find article about insert : 
  //http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/InsertdatausingSqlCommand.htm
}
```

Comment: i dnt want this . let me explain briefly . consider in this page 3 images are displaying . I want to get url of all images on button click event

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all available image urls:

```
var imageList = new List<Image>();
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
   if (control is Image)
   {
     imageList.Add((Image)control);
   }
}
foreach (Image img in imageList)
  //Can store all available image url
```

Thanks 
Sibabrata
[Mindfire Solutions](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com)